# how can i connect my java swing software (made in eclipse) to fetch data from my website

Tags: java, swing

I have made a java swing software using eclipse and i want it to connect to my shopify admin dashboard to fetch data .
Please suggest me possible ways with code-snippets(if possible).

Comment: Please include the code that you think is causing the issue, what you have tried / sources you've read to solve to the problem, and any error messages you may be getting.

Answer (score 0):

Some but not all Shopify admin dashboard data can be accessed via the Shopify API. There's no specific object for Shopify admin dashboard data.